# Swift 3 timed event

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift3

I have the following:

```
    let processURLS = processingViewController()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                         target: self,
                         selector: #selector(processURLS.getURLsToSend),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: true)
```

When this event is triggered, I received the following error and I'm not sure why this doesn't work

> 2016-11-09 14:47:00.504932 AcumenJLR[3414:905978] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[AcumenJLR.homeViewController getURLsToSend]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x100d25c60'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1816721c0 0x1800ac55c 0x181679278 0x181676278 0x18157059c 0x18215c8f8 0x1816208f4 0x181620608
>   0x18161fec4 0x18161dac0 0x18154c048 0x182fd2198 0x1875372fc
>   0x187532034 0x100114620 0x1805305b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is the getURLsToSend method

```
func getURLsToSend () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<URLsToSend> = URLsToSend.fetchRequest()
    let context = getContext()
    do {
        //Get results
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")

        //You need to convert to NSManagedObject to use 'for' loops
        for urls in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
            //print("\(urls.value(forKey: "url"))")
            let currentURL = urls.value(forKey: "url")!
            //print(urls.value(forKey: "url")!)

            completeLoadAction(urlString: currentURL as! String) { code in
                if (code == 200){
                    context.delete(urls)
                }
            }

        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: It happens because you don't have `getURLsToSend` function in the controller class

Comment: Try to keep a reference to your `processURLS` then change the selector to `target: self,.processUrl selector: #selector(getURLsToSend)`. I think that your variable processURL has been removed from memory so the selector cannot execute. Update:

Comment: But it seems also that the selector is not correct, you have to use *target* = `processUrls` and the *selector* = `getURLsToSend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the target / action pattern the method specified in `selector` must be declared in the class specified in `target` in this case the current class `self`.

Either change the `target` or implement the method in `self`.

Answer (score -1):

May be you have some paramter in method but you are not sending any value from there